# sorting 1d array in VB

Tags: arrays, vba, sorting

I wrote a 1D array sorting code, however the first value disappears after sorting. Here is my code:

```
For i = 0 To 10 - 1
    For j = 0 To (10 - 1) - i
        If Xs(j) > Xs(j + 1) Then
            tmp = Xs(j)
            Xs(j) = Xs(j + 1)
            Xs(j + 1) = tmp
        End If
    Next j 
Next i
```

Original array:

```
 0.995136318967065 
 1.92659411953677E-02 
 0.075211466386023 
 0.276865639306513 
 0.796949177428061 
 0.644136557566409 
 0.912439108707731 
 0.318021611061513 
 0.863316048056547 
 0.469710111256482
```

Array after sorting:

```
 0 
 1.92659411953677E-02 
 0.075211466386023
 0.276865639306513 
 0.318021611061513 
 0.469710111256482 
 0.644136557566409 
 0.796949177428061 
 0.863316048056547 
 0.912439108707731
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you have dimensioned your array `0 To 10`:

```
Dim Xs(0 To 10)
```

so creating 11 spaces into it. However, you have only 10 of them so you will have an *Empty* cell that will put itself on the first position at some point of the loop (being it evaluated as `0`, which is indeed the lowest value into your dataset).

I also believe you have dimensioned your array `0 To 10` instead of `0 To 9` because, if not, you would have got an `Subscript out of range error` in this part of the code:

```
For j = 0 To (10 - 1) - i
```

In order to make your code work:

a) Change the `Dim Xs(0 To 10)` to `Dim Xs(0 To 9)`

b) Change the `For j = 0 To (10 - 1) - i` to `For j = 0 To (10 - 1) - i-1`

Comment: @user3819984 please accept the answer if it worked ;)